# Origin of the 260/280 ratio?

Tags: rna, lab-techniques, dna-isolation

This is not a duplicate of all the other 260/280 ratio questions, I already know that DNA is supposed to be 1.8 and RNA is supposed to be 2.0. However, this might be more appropriate for chemistry, and will move it if I have to.

My question has to do with the Poly A tails on mRNA. I've been doing in vitro transcription and tailing for a while now and have noticed that the untailed RNA has a 260/280 of about 2.0, like you'd expect, but successful tailing results in ratios from 2.15 to 2.45, with higher ratios correlating to better band shifts on agarose gels, implying a longer tail. I suspect the reason for this is because the adenine has a much higher 260/280 than the other bases, so if you add a lot of adenines to the 3' end of the RNA you add much more 260 absorbance than 280 absorbance.

After seeing this I tried to come up with a mathematical method to estimate tail length based on 260/280, since gels are annoying, while I can get the ratio directly from the nanodrop.

I started by using the 260/280 for each nucleotide, A: 4.50, G: 1.15, C: 1.51, U: 4.00, T: 1.47 source here: [1](http://www.bio.davidson.edu/projects/gcat/protocols/NanoDrop_tip.pdf). I then took the sequence for the Luciferase gene I'm using for mRNA and counted the nucleotides, 449 A, 566 C, 470 G, 374 U. I tried to get the weighted average of the 260/280 for my RNA.

```
A: 449 x 4.50 = 2020.50
C: 566 x 1.51 =  854.60
G: 470 x 1.15 =  540.50
U: 374 x 4.00 = 1496.00
Sum:            4911.60

Nucleotides: 449 + 566 + 470 + 374 = 1859
Sum / Nucleotides : 4911.60 / 1859 = 2.64
```

2.64 is clearly not 2.0. Even accounting for the potential effect of pH and ionic strength on RNA 260/280 ( acidic solutions have lower ratios ) I can't explain why the calculated ratio is so high. Even if we assumed an RNA with 25% of each base, the weighted average is still (1.15 + 4.50 + 1.51 + 4.00)/4 = 2.79, even higher than for my real sequence.

Doing the same calculation for DNA, (1.15 + 4.50 + 1.51 + 1.47)/4 = 2.16.

So why don't my calculated ratios for RNA and DNA 260/280 match the "ideal" ratios of 2.0 and 1.8?

Comment: I bet it has something to do with base stacking interactions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one explanation: It's not the base composition that determines UV absorbance (260 nm), but whether the nucleic acid is in a single- or double stranded state.

[Promega](https://www.promega.de/resources/pubhub/enotes/why-does-denatured-dna-absorb-more-ultraviolet-light-than/) cites Griffiths biochemical methods that claims that double-stranded DNA absorbs UV less strongly than denatured DNA due to the stacking interactions between the bases.

I think your calculations must be wrong, since you can not expect a polymer to have the same spectrometric behaviour as the sum of all monomers. The absorbance of a molecule depends on its surroundings (like solvent, or nearby chemical groups). Bases within a DNA strand have much less contact to the solvent (H2O) when compared to a single nucleotide. In general, bases in ssRNA (single stranded RNA) and dsDNA interact with each other via aromatic pi-stacking. This affects the energies of the electrons that are responsible for light absorbance.

Most importantly, each base inside a dsDNA strand is engaged with a hydrogen bond from the other strand, which (I presume) significantly shifts electron energies and hence also its absorbance behavior. This might also be the reason why [low pH decreases UV absorption of RNA (260 nm)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/14145319_Effect_of_pH_and_Ionic_Strength_on_the_Spectrophotometric_Assessment_of_Nucleic_Acid_Purity), since hydrogen acceptors are protonated just like in the double stranded state.

Comment: Seems reasonable in general, but polyA would surely be single-stranded and, hence, unstacked, which would give a higher value than obtained. I just wonder how one gets enough mRNA to do an accurate 260/280.

Comment: Pi stacking happens in any single stranded nucleic acid. I presume that user137 somehow accumulated luciferase mRNA using e.g. in vitro transcription.